# Do we really need security updates on docker images

Tags: security, docker, containers

This question has come to my mind many times and I just wanted everyone to pitch in with their thoughts on same. 
The first thing that comes to my mind is container is not a VM and is almost equivalent to a process running in isolation in the host instance. Then why do we need to keep updating our docker images with security updates? If we have taken sufficient steps to secure our host instance then docker container should be safe. And even if we think from a different direction of multi layered security if the docker host is compromised then then there is no way to stop hacker from accessing all the containers running on the host; no matter how many security updates you did on the docker image. 
Are there any particular scenarios which anybody can share where security updates for docker images has really helped?
Now I understand if somebody want's to update apache running in the container however are there reasons to do OS level security updates for images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- an exploit can be dangerous even if it does not give you access to the underlying operating system. Just being able to do something within the application itself can be a big issue. For example, imagine you could inject scripts into Stackoverflow, impersonate other users, or obtain a copy of the complete user database.
- just like any software, Docker (and the underlying OS-provided container mechanism) is not perfect and can also have bugs. As such, there may be ways to bypass the isolation and break out of the sandbox.

Comment: your point 1 is talking about the application level security which the app running in container should take care of and hence doesn't look like anything to do with container image related security updates. Regarding point 2 : that is exactly my point however since everything in the scenario is handled at host instance level or via docker daemon. There still doesn't seem any scenario why we should worry about updating docker container images regularly.

Comment: For point 1, your application is most likely using functionality provided by the base image. For example image file decoding or URL parsing. Those are things that have been exploited before, and to protect against that you will want to pull in the relevant security patches via an updated base image. The scope of this is even broader when your base image is something like `java` or `wordpress`.

Comment: right so we're talking about pkgs from the image which are used by the container while running the app(eg. wordpress). I agree the example you gave makes sense. Updates like kernel updates doesn't make sense to me, any thoughts?

Comment: Kernel updates are not used by the container. It is running on the host kernel. Do base images even contain a kernel? It seems they should be limited to "userland" (and every part of that userland is potentially relevant for your application --- or if it is not, you could have stripped down the base image even more).